# Force value attribution in a table (R script)

Tags: r

I'm calculating particles diameter evolution over time and I'm trying to make the condition that when a particle diameter is less or equal to a minimal diameter the diameter is equal to the minimal fixed value.

I tried with the condition if but it is not working (code showed here bellow) So I would like to do is that from the first time the min diameter is reached what ever the other values are equal to, the min diameter value is attributed to them.

```
#p is my data frame and dp is diameter values
a <-p$diameter <- p$dp*((Te - p$t)/Te)^0.5
p$vol <- pi*(p$dp*1e-6)^3/6
#diam_min_ma is minimum diameter calculation
b <- diam_min_ma=(0.03*p$vol*6/pi)^(1/3)*1000000
c = if (a >= b)
    {p$diameter=a}  
    else 
    {p$diameter=b}
p$diameter <- c
```

This is an example of expected table (DP1,....Dp7 diameter change over time and Dp min is the minimum diameter that can be reached)

```
DpT1   DpT2   DpT3   DpT4   DpT5   DpT6  DpT7
150    100    75      50     36     36    36   Dp min= 36µm
100    60     45      30     28     28    28   Dp min= 28µm
 60    40     20      20     20     20    20   Dp min= 28µm
```

Comment: There is no `a` defined in the above code and the syntax of the code is also incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just forgot the "a" (copy error). I would like to know what is wrong in the code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer which was to use `ifelse` instead of what I did.
Which allow to do it for all table rows instead of only the first one

```
p$diameter <<- ifelse (a >= b,a,b)
```